# jpa entitymanager rollback not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my spring project i am using hibernate entitymanager. I have done transaction management in the project like below.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1527:selva" />
        <property name="username" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="yyy" />
</bean>
<bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.selva.entity</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>
```

**TestTranService.java**

```
@Transactional
    public String checkTranWork() {
        try {
            testTranDao.method1();
            int i=0;
            if(i==0)
                throw new ValidationException();
            testTranDao.method2();
            testTranDao.method3();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

TestTranDaoImpl.java

```
public class TestTranDaoImpl implements TestTranDao {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
            .getLogger(TestTranDaoImpl.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO CUST(MOBNUM,CUST_NAME) values ('1','dd')";
            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
            query.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
try {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO CUST(MOBNUM,CUST_NAME) values ('1','dd')";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



}
```

In my code after method 1 executing the insert statement i am throwing the exception so the first statement should be rolled back.But in my case rollback is not happened.Is their any other configuration required for rollback.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Catch` the `Exceptions` to log them, but then, you drop them. Don't do that!

An Exception has a meaning in a software, more than for logging, but also for all the framework around it.

Remove the `try catch` blocks so the `@Transactional` Aspect around your method can detect there's an error and rollback your transaction.

Comment: thanks Guillaume, After removing try catch rollback is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Gillaume for `@Transactional` to work, the method has to throw an exception then only the framework will know that `rollback` has to be performed. 
One solution already suggested is to remove the `try/catch` and if there is a need to catch the exception and log in application error log file then make sure the exception is propagated not consumed.
So the updated code would look like:

```
@Transactional
    public String checkTranWork() {
        try {
            testTranDao.method1();
            int i=0;
            if(i==0)
                throw new ValidationException();
            testTranDao.method2();
            testTranDao.method3();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return null;
    }
```